# CoreData - check if object exists in database

Tags: ios, core-data

I have viewController with table view and FetchResultsController. ViewController downloads data from web and then save it to CoreData. Downloading happens every launch. I need someway to compare info that I downloaded from web and only the save it to CoreData

How can I do this ?

I had an idea of fetching all objects by `fetchedResultsController.performFetch()` and then assigning them to array, but I dont understand how to iterate over that array (it us [AnyObject])

Maybe there are more easy ways ?

Comment: do the ones you download always win, or local versions of the objects win? do you have unique identifiers for all the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that out

I need to perform several steps in order to make comparison of content from core with array of custom objects

1) create empty array

```
var arrayOfReposOnDisk : [RepoObject] = []
```

2) fetch objects from CoreData

```
let fetchedData = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
```

3) iterate over `fetchedData` and convert each value for key-value to my custom object

```
for i in 0 ..< fetchedData!.count  {

        let object = fetchedData![i]

        let name = object.valueForKey("name") as! String
        let description = object.valueForKey("description") as! String
        let authorName = object.valueForKey("avatarURL") as! String
        let avatarURL = object.valueForKey("authorName") as! String
        let forks = object.valueForKey("forks") as! Int
        let watches = object.valueForKey("watches") as! Int

        let repoObject = RepoObject(name: name, description: description, authorName: authorName, avatarURL: avatarURL, forks: forks, watches: watches)

        arrayOfItemsOnDisk.append(repoObject)
    }
```

4) finally, make a comparison

```
if arrayOfReposOnDisk.contains ({ $0.name == name }) {
       print("There is the same name in json as in CoreData, doing nothing")
   } else {
       self.insertNewObject(name, descriptionText: description, avatarURL: avatarURL, authorName: authorName, forks: forks, watches: watches)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can used `fetchedObjects` on the fetched results controller. It is an array of `[AnyObject]?`, but you can cast it to your object type with something like

```
if let myObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as? [MyObjectType] {
    for object in myObjects {
        // do some comparison to see if the object is in your downloaded data
    }
}
```

Another way to get the objects is to create a `NSFetchRequest` and use `executeFetchRequest` on your managed object context.